# How to execute function before page rendering?

Tags: php, event-observer

I´m looking to program a module that will cache each page as HTML depending on the user status (logged in or not logged in).

If the user is not logged in the page must be cached as a HTML file (if not already cached), and if the page is already cached the cached HTML must be loaded as output instead of framework rendering the output (and this is where I need to know how and where to implement my functions)

To get started I need to know how I can hook into the Magento framework before pages are being rendered.
I have tried to dust up information about this, and it seems the answer could lie in the dispatch event "controller_front_init_before"

Does anyone know if "controller_front_init_before" is indeed the event I should use for my module?

Comment: If you're looking for a caching extension, you might want to look at lestiFPC which is free, or Varnish + Turpentine

Comment: Thanks. Wasn´t aware of LestiFpc. Looks promising. I will give it a try.

Comment: Although I like Lesti_Fpc a lot, I can recommend [DieHard](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Diehard) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a caching extension, you might want to look at lestiFPC which is free, or Varnish + Turpentine.

Like Fabian points out, DieHard might be interesting also!

Answer (score 2):

Although I like [Lesti_Fpc](https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc/) a lot, I can recommend [DieHard](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Diehard) as well.

And even if you don't want to use these, you can check what events they use.

Comment: Definitely looks interesting also! I personally prefer Varnish + Turpentine, but that can be a pain to set up if you don't have experience with it.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Even though I did give the answer to Milan for mentioning lestiFPC I should also give you a nod. DieHard also looks very good, in terms of providing the features I need.